# How to get contents of loaded page inside iframe in ionic 4 after click event

Tags: html, ionic-framework, iframe

Actually I am using iframe to load page in ionic and there is one scenario that when user click the button of page which loaded in iframe and have to open pdf inside my iOS app this will happen when if I get content of page which is trigger after button click event so how to get contents of page when click event happene?

i) In my html page I used iframe to display page like this

`<ion-content  class="iframe-wrapper">
  <iframe  [src]="this.safeUrl" id="InnerIframe">
    </iframe>`

ii) and in typescript I did like this for capturing events.

`//find iframe
     let iframe = $('#InnerIframe');
     //find button inside iframe
     let button = iframe.contents().find('#btn_view_263143');`

but it didn't work